# How to rebase a branch that has master merged into it?

Tags: git

I've run

```
git pull origin master
```

in my dev-branch to merge master into it. Now

```
git rebase -i origin/master
```

says there's merge conflicts that are not real. Incoming change is the 1st commit in the dev-branch (before the merge) and not current situation of the dev-branch.

Current situation of the dev-branch does not have any conflicts with master because master is just merged. The problem is that git thinks there is merge conflicts cause it compares master with old version of the dev-branch. i.e. 1st commit which in this case is also the commit just before merging master into it.

So how this should be done?

Comment: As a sort of general rule, rebasing when merges exist just should not be done. There are some exceptions, and if you'll include the actual commit graph (e.g., enough of the `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` output) and what result you'd like, someone can probably answer this more-specific variant.

Comment: i understand. however  i have 8 small commits in my branch and would like to have the history clean. i solved this one time by creating a new branch and rebasing that somehow and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are facing merge conflicts then unless you resolve the conflicts you wont be able to run any git operations unless you resolve the conflicts.
merge conflicts will occur if you try to change some files whose remote/master version also has some changes
For example you have some changes in abhi.text file and in master branch also abhi.text also has some changes which are not pulled to your local
And now you do git pull.....then you face this problem
Solution-->>

Before git pull try

**git stash**

to save the current new changed file and then do

**git pull**

Now do  —>>>

**git stash apply**

to get the local changes which were stashed
and then you may face CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict on specific file then go to Specific files do the changes like….you may get remote changes and local changes in unarranged manner ..so just arrange it keep local changes after remote changes

Now do—>>>

**git commit and push**

Comment: After resolving conflicts only you will be able to run command like rebase or any

Comment: i'm asking a specific question. i'm not asking what are merge conflicts. after merging master into dev-branch the rebase thinks there's conflicts even tho master is just pulled and all merge conflicts are solved.

Comment: Rebase rebases one commit at the time. That the merge conflicts will *eventually* all be solved by your merge is of no consequence, the individual commits must now be resolved as well. This is one of the major differences between rebasing and merging, with merging you can resolve all the merge conflicts in one fell swoop (or there might even be none) whereas with rebasing all the individual commits must fit on top of the target and might have merge conflicts per commit.

Comment: thanks @LasseV.Karlsen! now i understand. so what if i had rebased instead of merge earlier to resolve the conflicts in my dev-branch? and then rebased again after few commits before merging it to master?

Comment: have no idea how that would've worked, most likely you would have to go through the same conflicts no matter